# How to fix an onclick event not getting triggered?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, mouseevent

The onclick event on button with role="menuitem" is not getting triggered but mouseover is getting triggered.

I have tried various things like instead of using an external function, I simplied made an alert but no benefit.

```js
        {{#each docs}}
        <li class="note" id={{this.time}}>
            <a href="#">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="more" id={{this.time}} onclick="openMenu(event)">
                        <button id={{this.time}} class="more-btn">
                            <span id={{this.time}} class="more-dot"></span>
                            <span id={{this.time}} class="more-dot"></span>
                            <span id={{this.time}} class="more-dot"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="more-menu">
                            <div class="more-menu-caret">
                                <div class="more-menu-caret-outer"></div>
                                <div class="more-menu-caret-inner"></div>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="more-menu-items" tabindex="-1" role="menu" aria-labelledby="more-btn"
                                aria-hidden="true">
                                <li class="more-menu-item" role="presentation">
                                    <button type="button" class="more-menu-btn" role="menuitem" onclick="updateNote(event)">Update me</button>
                                </li>
                                <li class="more-menu-item" role="presentation" >
                                    <button type="button" id ="rome" class="more-menu-btn" role="menuitem" onclick="deleteNote(event)" >Delete</button>
                                </li>
                                <li class="more-menu-item" role="presentation">
                                    <button type="button" class="more-menu-btn" role="menuitem" onclick="toggleReminder(event)">
                                        {{#if this.remind}}
                                        Unset Reminder
                                        {{else}}
                                        Set reminder
                                        {{/if}}
                                    </button>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is the external js file:

```js
function openMenu(event) {
  var elList = document.getElementsByClassName('more');
  var el;
  for (var i = 0; i < elList.length; i++) {
    el = elList[i];
    if (el.id === event.target.id)
      break;
  }

  var btn = el.querySelector('.more-btn');
  var menu = el.querySelector('.more-menu');
  var menuItems = el.querySelector('.more-menu-items');
  var visible = false;

  function showMenu(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!visible) {
      visible = true;
      el.classList.add('show-more-menu');
      menu.setAttribute('aria-hidden', false);
      menuItems.setAttribute('aria-hidden', false);
      document.addEventListener('mousedown', hideMenu, false);
    }
  }

  function hideMenu(e) {
    if (btn.contains(e.target)) {
      return;
    }
    if (visible) {
      visible = false;
      el.classList.remove('show-more-menu');
      menu.setAttribute('aria-hidden', true);
      menuItems.setAttribute('aria-hidden', true);
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', hideMenu);
    }
  }


  btn.addEventListener('click', showMenu, false);
  el.addEventListener('mouseleave', hideMenu, false)
  $('#rome').click(alertHye);
}



function deleteNote(e) {
  console.log(e.target)
}
```

What's happening is nothing, not even a console error. Expected is a console log.

Comment: These things are always tricky for some reason. I would try doing a `$(document).ready(function(){/*declare listener here*/});`

Comment: To elaborate on the above comment.  If you try to attach a listener to an element that you aren't sure hasn't rendered yet, it will fail silently.  Waiting for `$(document).ready()` guarantees that the DOM has settled and your elements exist.

Comment: `$(document).ready()` isn't required here. None of this code executes prior to the document being completely rendered because it is driven by in-line event attributes. The problem may very likely be associated with the reuse of the `id` attribute values (which is a no-no).